# What is the difference between the JQuery and the JQueryStatic interface in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Can someone explain this? I realize the jQuery interface is the one that comes pre defined but what is JQueryStatic?

I have the following:

```
(function($)
{

    $.fn.disableBt = function()
    {
        $(this).attr('disabled', true);
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9)
        {
            $(this).addClass('disabled');
        }
    }

})(jQuery);
```

The only way I could get typescript to know about this was by adding it to the jQuery interface like this:

```
    disableBt();
}
```

I tried adding it to jQueryStatic but it didn't seem to work:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
  modal( options );
  disableBt();
}
```

Here's the way options is defined in my modal:

```
$.modal.defaults = {
    content: false,
    useIframe: false,
    ...
    ...
var settings = $.extend({}, $.modal.defaults, options),
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is "options" (in modal (options)) defined?

JQueryStatic interface has the static methods ("those on $ and jQuery themselves")

JQuery interface has the members that can be run on jQuery elements, many of them are returning JQuery themselves for chainability.

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    someAdditionalMethod(): any;
}
$.someAdditionalMethod();

interface JQuery {
    pluginMethod(): JQuery;
}
$("body").pluginMethod();
```

if your case something like this:

```
interface ModalDefaultOptions {
    content?: bool;
    useIframe?: bool;
}

interface JQueryStatic {
    modal: {
        defaults: ModalDefaultOptions;
    };
}

interface JQuery {
    disableBt(): void; // or :JQuery if you returned 'this' from the function 
}

$("#someButton").disableBt();
$.modal.defaults.content = false;
```

Comment: @jeoriks - I just added to my question the way options is declared/defined. I am not really sure how or if I could add that definition information with typescript. Is it possible? Am I correct in saying that if I declare foo(): any then that will allow any combination of parameters for foo and typescript won't do checking on them?

Comment: Following on from what you said. Am I correct in saying that the only interface I should need to extend is JQueryStatic and there's no reason I would need to extend the JQuery interface?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread the original question. I updatd my answer now. I'd begin defining the members as any (modal:any), see if it works as expected, then I'd add the detailed types.

Comment: make sure if you're using modules not to put the `JQuery` interface declaration inside your module. it must be in the global top level namespace or you'd be defining your own JQuery interface instead of merging into the $ one